# To creation session id using SQL Query for wifi log user events

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

Friends,

The scenario is related to wifi controllers log file where in users activity is tracked like when user "joins", "in", disconnects from" and "leave" from the wifi network. I have cleaned and uploaded the structured data in a table. I want to create session id's at user level for his/her activities. Identified that one session can be grouped by all events between the event "joins" and "leave". I have attached the sample data for better understanding.

Some pointers useful for the creation of the session id's :

1. a new session for the users can be identified by "joins" event and end is denoted by "leave" event.
2. "disconnects from" and "leave" have same timestamp, hence there order can be random if ordered by timestamp.
3. for every "disconnects from" there is an entry for "leave" but not vice versa. Therefore we can have "leave" without "disconnects from" records.
4. "in" denotes roaming so it should be part of the same session. It will between "joins" and "leave" events.
5. you may see the records having only "in" or say "disconnects from" only because the complete log file was not available, still want to tag these as different session id.

Please help me to create the session id's considering the given pointers. Below is the sample data with few possible scenarios for better understanding what I am looking for. The "required data" has been assigned with dummy session id's, this is how it should look. Post me for any further clarification. I want to achieve this using SQL.

## Scenario 1

### raw data:

`usermac            datetime                event`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 09:30:58.000 joins
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 09:51:54.000 in
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 09:51:54.000 in
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 12:01:39.000 disconnects from
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 12:01:39.000 leave
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 12:46:05.000 joins
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 15:27:28.000 disconnects from
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 15:27:28.000 leave
```

### required format:

`usermac                datetime                event           sessionid`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 09:30:58.000 joins               1
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 09:51:54.000 in                  1
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 09:51:54.000 in                  1
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 12:01:39.000 disconnects from    1
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 12:01:39.000 leave               1
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 12:46:05.000 joins               2
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 15:27:28.000 disconnects from    2
xx:xx:xx:xx:0e:72   2018-04-19 15:27:28.000 leave               2
```

## Scenario 2

### raw data:

`usermac            datetime                event`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:35:48.000 joins
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:40:01.000 leave
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:40:01.000 disconnects from
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:40:08.000 joins
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:43:45.000 leave
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:43:45.000 disconnects from
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:44:00.000 joins
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 22:01:29.000 leave
```

### required format:

`usermac                datetime                event           sessionid`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:35:48.000 joins               3
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:40:01.000 leave               3
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:40:01.000 disconnects from    3
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:40:08.000 joins               4
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:43:45.000 leave               4
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:43:45.000 disconnects from    4
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 21:44:00.000 joins               5
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:80   2018-04-12 22:01:29.000 leave               5
```

## Scenario 3

### raw data:

`usermac            datetime                event`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 09:15:18.000 joins               
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 11:02:30.000 in                  
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 11:02:30.000 in                  
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 11:06:09.000 disconnects from    
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 11:06:09.000 leave               
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 11:07:03.000 joins               
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 13:35:51.000 leave
```

### required format:

`usermac                datetime                event           sessionid`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 09:15:18.000 joins               6
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 11:02:30.000 in                  6
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 11:02:30.000 in                  6
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 11:06:09.000 disconnects from    6
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 11:06:09.000 leave               6
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 11:07:03.000 joins               7
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:92   2018-04-23 13:35:51.000 leave               7
```

## Scenario 4

### raw data:

`usermac            datetime                event`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:03:24.000 disconnects from
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:03:24.000 leave
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:05:45.000 joins
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:05:48.000 leave
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:05:48.000 disconnects from
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:31:59.000 joins
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:32:02.000 leave
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:32:02.000 disconnects from
```

### required format:

`usermac                datetime                event           sessionid`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:03:24.000 disconnects from    8
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:03:24.000 leave               8
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:05:45.000 joins               9
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:05:48.000 leave               9
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:05:48.000 disconnects from    9
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:31:59.000 joins               10
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:32:02.000 leave               10
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:5f   2018-06-23 07:32:02.000 disconnects from    10
```

## Scenario 5

### raw data:

`usermac            datetime                event`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b2   2018-06-12 07:22:14.000 in          
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b2   2018-06-12 07:22:14.000 in
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b2   2018-06-12 07:22:40.000 in
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b2   2018-06-12 07:22:40.000 in
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b2   2018-06-12 07:23:39.000 leave
```

### required format:

`usermac                datetime                event           sessionid`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b2   2018-06-12 07:22:14.000 in               11
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b2   2018-06-12 07:22:14.000 in               11
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b2   2018-06-12 07:22:40.000 in               11
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b2   2018-06-12 07:22:40.000 in               11
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b2   2018-06-12 07:23:39.000 leave            11
```

## Scenario 6

### raw data:

`usermac            datetime                event`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:16   2018-06-23 07:55:26.000 in
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:16   2018-06-23 07:55:26.000 in
```

### required format:

`usermac                datetime                event           sessionid`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:16   2018-06-23 07:55:26.000 in               12
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:16   2018-06-23 07:55:26.000 in               12
```

## Scenario 7

### raw data:

`usermac            datetime                event`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:m6   2018-06-24 06:56:30.000 rejoins
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:m6   2018-06-24 06:56:51.000 rejoins
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:m6   2018-06-24 06:56:59.000 leave
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:m6   2018-06-24 06:56:59.000 disconnects from
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:m6   2018-06-24 06:57:03.000 joins
```

### required format:

`usermac                datetime                event           sessionid`

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:m6   2018-06-24 06:56:30.000 rejoins           13
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:m6   2018-06-24 06:56:51.000 rejoins           13
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:m6   2018-06-24 06:56:59.000 leave             13
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:m6   2018-06-24 06:56:59.000 disconnects from  13
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:m6   2018-06-24 06:57:03.000 joins             14
```

Things tried till now:

`with cte1 as 
     (
     SELECT row_number() over(partition by usermac
       ORDER BY  datetime) indexno, 
       row_number() over(partition by  event 
       ORDER BY  usermac, datetime) sessionid, datetime, usermac, event
       from t8_wfc_log_apr_jun_syslog_cast  where usermac='xx:xx:xx:xx:16' order by usermac, datetime
       )
 SELECT case when event = 'joins' then 
         sessionid 
         else
            (select max(sessionid) from cte1 innie where innie.usermac = oute.usermac and innie.indexno < oute.indexno and   innie.event = 'joins') end sessionid,
        datetime,
        usermac,
        event
FROM cte1 oute order by usermac, datetime;`

Comment: What did you do so far ?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...